# Moment js: format date without zero padding

Tags: javascript, date, format, momentjs

How can I format a date with momentjs without leading zeros? E.g. 2018-6-29 instead of 2018-06-29.

If the number is smaller than 10 it should not add 0 before it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the docs (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) if you use `M` or `D` instead of `MM` or `DD` in the format() function you will get the date without the 0.

`moment().format("YYYY-M-DD")` is what you are after.

if you also want to exclude the 0 from single digit days you can use:

```
moment().format("YYYY-M-D")
```

(fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/69671/)

Comment: thanks, i tried that but got error, but other thing caused it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the format string `YYYY-M-D`.

Consult the documentation of how to format moments. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/